# Importing library in react code throws compilation error

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, rabbitmq

When trying to consume messages from rabbitmq from my react project for which I use the following import

```
import amqp from 'amqplib'
```

`npm install amqplib` is already done. `amqplib` is the library suggested by rabbitmq official docs itself. But even before adding any code using the installed library, with just the import, I always get the following error: This is the case for

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/amqplib/lib/connect.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in 'C:\Users\arun\Desktop\projects\react\amq-test\node_modules\amqplib\lib'
```

What is the missing piece here?

Comment: Have you run a full ```npm install``` in the project root directory?

Comment: @Ryan no. Pardon me, I am new to the node world. May I know what is the command I need to run for this? is it just `npm install`?

Comment: It can't resolve 'net' so you should install `net` with `npm install net`

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed **net** package. As a solution run this command on your terminal

```
npm i -s net
```

After that run your project again. If any error occurred try to remove **node_modules** folder and run `npm install`

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem in my react app. I solved by installing (`npm i assert buffer ...`) these modules;

- assert
- buffer
- net
- querysting
- stream
- tls
- util