# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'util' in webpack

Tags: webpack

when i run the script it show me this errors
Here is error:

BREAKING CHANGE:`webpack` < 5 used to include `polyfills` for `node.js` core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a `polyfill` for it.

If you want to include a `polyfill`, you need to: add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { `"util"`: require.resolve("`util`/") }', install `'util'`;
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:resolve.fallback: { `"util"`: false }
@ ./node_modules/`webpack`/lib/index.js 74:30-50 77:9-29
@ ./src/googlesheets.js 21:16-34
@ ./src/index.js 1:0-44 2:0-10

Comment: I have the same problem. Please look at here, https://stackoverflow.com/a/72858182/621951

Answer (score 77):

The main problem is with Webpack 5. It doesn't preload the polyfill of Node.js. I see that this issue can help you. https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/11282

To solve it: `npm install util`, and add it into `webpack.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  // ...
  resolve: {
      fallback: {
        util: require.resolve("util/")
      }
  }
  // ...
};
```

Comment: @Th3Cod3- sir but in angular webpack.config.js dosent exist..tell me any another file for angular?

Comment: @KapilSoni the default Angular builder does not allow modification of the webpack config. You need to use a different builder like https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-builders/custom-webpack

Comment: @SteveSanders this is not great advice sadly. Ejecting the entire Angular build system just to fix a dependency is insane.

Comment: I don't understand why `webpack.config.js` is set up with CommonJS (`require`) modules. Isn't WebPack supposed to emit ES modules? This looks like a good answer if it were an ES module.

Answer (score 28):

For me, it was enough to do `yarn add util` (alternatively, `npm install util`). I didn't have to add it to any other files.

Comment: Same for me.  I'm using  create react app with typescript and deploying to Cloudflare so no webpack or anything else going on

Comment: I ran into this error while attempting to install Storybook into an NextJS app. Just running `yarn add util` cleared up the error for me.

Comment: The purpose with fallback module is that it will only use your installed `util` package in fallback condition. Meaning in case `util` is not provided in the runtime environment.

Answer (score 24):

If your code is multi-target (node & browser), follow the other answers. If your code will only run on nodejs, this suffices:

```js
    module.exports = {
     target: "node", // Or "async-node"
     mode: "production" /* or "development", or "none" */
     /* ... */
    }
```

Answer (score 9):

If you do not have `util`, and do not even use `webpack.config.ts`

1. `npm install util`
2. make the following changes to your `tsconfig.json`

```json
    "angularCompilerOptions": {
         "types" : ["node"]
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

For angular apps, do `npm install util` and go to `polyfills.ts`.
Add `import 'util/util.js';` at last under APPLICATION IMPORTS

Answer (score 3):

After some struggling and searching around, I have found a solution for Vue3 app (I was trying to run `jsonwebtoken` on frontend):

1. install `node-polyfill-webpack-plugin`
2. in vue.config.js file (create one if you don't have it) add:

```
const NodePolyfillPlugin = require("node-polyfill-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: (config) => {
    config.plugin("polyfills").use(NodePolyfillPlugin);
  },
};
```

[credits here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71567424/16195543)

Answer (score 1):

Last comment was very helpful, after that I've added:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vpOl.png)

after modifying resolve, install with npm all of those packages one by one.

Answer (score 1):

I installed the util package using the below command on the terminal:

```
npm i util --force
```

I Had to use --force above as there were some version dependency issues.

Then i created the web.config.js in the main directory of the react app and added the below code in it:

```
module.exports = {
    resolve:{
        fallback: {
            util: require.resolve("util/")
        }
    }
}
```

This resolved the util webpack issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

with ioni Cli 6 and ionic Framwork 6.0.16  i managed to solve it by going to ionic nodemodule folder :

`/Users/Projects/my_APP/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/webpack/configs/browser.js`

inside this block of code

```
function getBrowserConfig(wco) {
 return {
        devtool: false,
        resolve: {
            mainFields: ['es2015', 'browser', 'module', 'main'],
            fallback: {  //added this line
                dgram: false,  //added this line
                fs: false,  //added this line
                net: false,  //added this line
                tls: false,  //added this line
                util: false,  //added this line
                https: false,   //added this line
                crypto: false,   //added this line
                assert: false,   //added this line
                stream: false,   //added this line
                http: false,   //added this line
                zlib : false,   //added this line
                path: false   //added this line

              }    //added this line
           
        },
  
        node: false,
      
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I jsut runt into this while trying to use `jsonwebtoken` for verifying a JWT in my Angular app. After trying some of the suggestions above without success I gave up in used the [jose package](https://github.com/panva/jose) instead (as suggested in [this post](https://serveanswer.com/questions/why-cant-i-use-jwt-verify-from-jsonwebtoken-in-react); it refers to [a list of libraries at JWT.io)](https://jwt.io/libraries?language=JavaScript).

Answer (score 0):

Adding **providers** fixed this error in my case.

```
@Component({
    selector: "basic-data",
    templateUrl: "./basic-data.component.html",
    styleUrls: ["./basic-data.component.scss"],
    providers: [BasicDataStore], <-- Fixed the error
})
export class BasicDataComponent {
    constructor(
        private readonly basicDataStore: BasicDataStore,
    ) {}
}
```

*(...Installing utils etc. didn't help.)*

Answer (score 0):

This issue is solved by running below command in my case:
npm install util --force

Answer (score -1):

My problem was fixed when I did this:

1. Go to the node_modules folder
2. Search for the react-scripts folder
3. Inside config folder, you will see `webpack.config.js` file.
4. Under the resolve part in ine number 303, add this

```
resolve: {
  fallback: {
    util: require.resolve("util/")
  },
// ...
}
```

Comment: I believe content of "node_modules" should not be manually modified as it will change on a package update and will not be working for other people You could cooperate with (after they do `npm install` they will not have this change).

Answer (score -3):

We need just to run

> npm audit fix --force

to address all issues.

Comment: Is this comment malicious sarcasm? Doing this on a large project is extremely likely to break something. Hopefully something obvious, but not necessarily.