# Module not found angular

Tags: angular, node-modules

After I updated my angular project from 12 to 13 version I got a lot of module errors when I ran ng serve --o. How I can fix it?

```
 BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "util": require.resolve("util/") }'
        - install 'util'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "util": false }

./node_modules/cacache/lib/util/tmp.js:6:13-28 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'D:\StudenBook\node_modules\cacache\lib\util'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
        - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "path": false }

./node_modules/cacache/lib/verify.js:3:13-28 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'util' in 'D:\StudenBook\node_modules\cacache\lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "util": require.resolve("util/") }'
        - install 'util'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "util": false }

./node_modules/cacache/lib/verify.js:8:11-24 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'D:\StudenBook\node_modules\cacache\lib'

./node_modules/cacache/lib/verify.js:12:13-28 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'D:\StudenBook\node_modules\cacache\lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
        - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "path": false }

./node_modules/cacache/rm.js:3:13-28 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'util' in 'D:\StudenBook\node_modules\cacache'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "util": require.resolve("util/") }'
        - install 'util'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "util": false }

./node_modules/cacache/rm.js:7:13-28 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'D:\StudenBook\node_modules\cacache'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
        - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "path": false }

./node_modules/chownr/chownr.js:2:11-24 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'D:\StudenBook\node_modules\chownr'

./node_modules/chownr/chownr.js:3:13-28 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'D:\StudenBook\node_modules\chownr'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
        - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "path": false }

./node_modules/detect-libc/lib/detect-libc.js:3:15-37 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'os' in 'D:\StudenBook\node_modules\detect-libc\lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "os": require.resolve("os-browserify/browser") }'
        - install 'os-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "os": false }

./node_modules/detect-libc/lib/detect-libc.js:4:16-50 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in 'D:\StudenBook\node_modules\detect-libc\lib'

./node_modules/detect-libc/lib/detect-libc.js:5:18-43 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'D:\StudenBook\node_modules\detect-libc\lib'

./node_modules/fs-minipass/index.js:4:11-24 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'D:\StudenBook\node_modules\fs-minipass'

./node_modules/fs.realpath/index.js:8:9-22 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'D:\StudenBook\node_modules\fs.realpath'

./node_modules/fs.realpath/old.js:22:17-32 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'D:\StudenBook\node_modules\fs.realpath'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
        - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "path": false }

./node_modules/fs.realpath/old.js:24:9-22 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'D:\StudenBook\node_modules\fs.realpath'

./node_modules/gauge/lib/error.js:2:11-26 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'util' in 'D:\StudenBook\node_modules\gauge\lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "util": require.resolve("util/") }'
        - install 'util'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "util": false }

./node_modules/glob/common.js:13:11-26 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'D:\StudenBook\node_modules\glob'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
        - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "path": false }

./node_modules/glob/glob.js:43:9-22 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'D:\StudenBook\node_modules\glob'

./node_modules/glob/glob.js:49:11-26 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'D:\StudenBook\node_modules\glob'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
        - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "path": false }

./node_modules/glob/glob.js:50:13-30 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'assert' in 'D:\StudenBook\node_modules\glob'
```

And more others module errors... Please help me

Comment: Read the error messages, then search for the error message on your favorite search engine, discover that this is something others have seen before, then do something to correct the problem. Basics of troubleshooting, really. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64402821/module-not-found-error-cant-resolve-util-in-webpack

Comment: So, I found out my problem; All of troubleshooting was cuz of bcrypt module, I deleted it. I installed it previous. Don't know why its caused so many troubles

Answer (score 1):

> you may need to use npm install to install all your lost modules
>
> for example for your util module error, use this command to reinstall
> it again:

**npm i util**

Comment: So, I can't install all of them in the same time?

Comment: use this command: npm i --force

Comment: i tried, but nothig. I'll try to install every module separately

Comment: I hope it works