# Error: Can't resolve 'net' after adding the rabbitode package to my React app

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, node-amqplib

Just added [rabbitode](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rabbitode) to my React TypeScript app so I can read from RabbitMQ. The instructions are quite straightforward, however, I hit a number of issues after installation. My module doesn't compile at all. There were a number of issues related to my using webpack 5, as described here [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64580815/2932714). Most of these could be resolved with the provided answer (`util`, `buffer` and `querystring-es3`) but I'm getting no joy with `stream-browserify`. Also, there are a couple of errors that I can't track down at all:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/rabbitode/node_modules/amqplib/lib/connect.js 155:11-33

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in 'c:\myapp\node_modules\rabbitode\node_modules\amqplib\lib'
```

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/rabbitode/node_modules/amqplib/lib/connect.js 157:11-33

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tls' in 'c:\myapp\node_modules\rabbitode\node_modules\amqplib\lib'
```

The lines the error is about are:

```
  if (protocol === 'amqp:') {
    sock = require('net').connect(sockopts, onConnect);
  }
  else if (protocol === 'amqps:') {
    sock = require('tls').connect(sockopts, onConnect);
  }
  else {
    throw new Error("Expected amqp: or amqps: as the protocol; got " + protocol);
  }
```

Thought this could be related to my node version as `net` and `tls` are available libraries
according to the [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html) but the issue remains.

Any idea about how to fix it??

Also, the stream error is:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/rabbitode/node_modules/amqplib/lib/connection.js 18:13-37

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'c:\myapp\node_modules\rabbitode\node_modules\amqplib\lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }'
    - install 'stream-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "stream": false }
```

That I tried resolving by running `npm install stream-browserify` and adding `stream: require.resolve("stream-browserify"),` to the the `fallback` object in the webpack config. Why would this not work??

### UPDATE

I think the problem is related to a couple of key facts:

1. I bootstrapped my application with the `create-react-app` and therefore by webpack config was ignored
2. `rabbitode` is relying on packages that were not meant for browser use.

I think the solution here is to look for a library that is more fit for purpose (or add an `SseEmitter` into my SpringBoot backend that reads from the queue, then read its contents in the client via an `EventSource`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the author of the package, unfortunately it's not meant for use on frontend applications it's meant for node.js servers.

If you did find a workaround to get it working on the frontend I'd love to hear it and I'll see if I can add native support to it :)

Thanks
Evan

Comment: I ended up implementing the `SseEmitter`-`EventSource` combination, works like a charm.